# Transaction scope in windows workflow foundation

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have used the transaction scope activity in windows workflow foundation. I am getting an workflow SQL persistence error.

I am not having SQL persistence database.

Do we need persisetence services.

I am not having Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC)

Answer (score 2):

The transaction scope in Windows Workflow Foundation 3.x requires a WorkflowPersistenceService that supports transactions to work.  The SqlPersistenceService provided out of the box works for this, and you can also write your own.